# Java Import Package (to package above present work directory)

Tags: java, import, package

how do I import package (to package above present work directory) in Java?

here is the directory structure:

[image]

**Coba.java**

```
import halo.*;

public class Coba
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Orang org = new Orang();
        System.out.println(org.a);
    }
}
```

**Orang.java**

```
package halo;
// I can't import kabar.*; since it's above present work directory

public class Orang
{
    public int a;

    public Orang()
    {
        this.a = 1;
    }

    public void haha()
    {
        /*
            i want to:
            Tes t = new Tes();
            System.out.println(t.b);
        */
    }
}
```

**Tes.java**

```
package kabar;

public class Tes
{
    public int b;

    public Tes()
    {
        this.b = 2;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

How do I access variable b in class Tes by importing class kabar.Tes from class Orang?

If i write

```
import kabar.Tes;
```

in class Orang. It doesn't work because class Orang is above present work directory.

Thank you very much.

BTW, I don't use Netbeans or Eclipse. I want to know the basic how it works, so I just use simple text editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David,
The location of the directories doesn't matter.  It's the packages that matter.  You can add multiple directories to your classpath when you compile/run the program to refer to these extra directories.

Comment: Hi, thank you for "You can add multiple directories to your classpath when you compile/run the program to refer to these extra directories"

Comment: It works now. I compile Orang.java with : 1) cd halo 2) javac -cp ../ Orang.java . Again, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You need to read some very basic tutorials.  This particular topic is covered [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html), and other Sun [tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/) might  be useful as well.